# Angular 7 unable to get value from class properties

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and Typescript and am trying to pass some class properties into an array that is defined in the same class. Please see the AppComponent class below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Columns from './dropdown';
import { Query } from './Query';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  keys = Object.keys;

  regions = Columns.Region;
  statuses = Columns.Status;
  languages = Columns.Language;
  types = Columns.Type; 

  searchQuery: string;
  selectedRegion: string;
  selectedStatus: string;
  selectedLanguage: string;
  selectedType: string;

  searchArray: string[] = [ this.searchQuery, this.selectedRegion, this.selectedStatus, this.selectedLanguage, this.selectedType ];

  QueryString = new Query(this.searchQuery, this.selectedRegion, this.selectedStatus, this.selectedLanguage, this.selectedType);
}
```

Then in my HTML if I just do

```
<div> {{searchArray}} </div>
```

nothing shows up. But if I do

```
<div>{{searchQuery}} + {{selectedLanguage}}</div>
```

then I can see the changes in the variable in real time as I type in the search box. 
Why is it that when I try to pass the values to an array the array ends up null?

I thought it was an asynchronous issue, as the properties probably do not have values when I make the call, but the fact that I can call searchQuery, selectedRegion, selectedStatus, etc and see them change on the page as I type in the search box and select from the dropdowns makes me think this is not the issue -- once it has a value, the value is displayed.

Then I thought it was because I did not have a constructor that initialized or set these variables, but they are bound to different input elements. They get their value from the user so I cannot set them myself. How will I be able to put these into an array and pass them to a function? I can add my HTML file if necessary.

Comment: When you set up searchArray it is pulling values from this.searchQuery etc which are null when the variables are created, QueryString gets called after and is also initially null. You do need to bind those values to your form either using Reactive forms or template forms each with their own method for doing so.

Comment: @PariBaker they are already bound to my form, and I can see their values when just using `<div>{{selectedStatus}}</div>`, for example. Are you saying that there is no way to pass these user input values to my array?

Comment: of course there is! if you are using reactive forms you can subscribe to the field and use the valueChanges to filter the value to a function.

Comment: If you are using template forms you can add a (blur)="foo($event.value)" to send the value to a function on blur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for could be done with a custom accessor:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Columns from './dropdown';
import { Query } from './Query';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  keys = Object.keys;

  regions = Columns.Region;
  statuses = Columns.Status;
  languages = Columns.Language;
  types = Columns.Type; 

  searchQuery: string;
  selectedRegion: string;
  selectedStatus: string;
  selectedLanguage: string;
  selectedType: string;

  public get searchArray(): string[] {
    return  [ this.searchQuery, this.selectedRegion, this.selectedStatus, this.selectedLanguage, this.selectedType ];
  }

  QueryString = new Query(this.searchQuery, this.selectedRegion, this.selectedStatus, this.selectedLanguage, this.selectedType);
}
```

Angular's change detection should pick up the changes when the variables are changed, because the array will be recreated each time it is accessed for the HTML. Your code doesn't work because it's creating the array initially with 5 undefined values, and then the array itself isn't updated afterwards.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly for me. I should look more into Angular's accessors. Thank you